# keep most recent observations when there are duplicates in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have the following data.

```
  date                         var1    level       score_1     score_2
   2020-02-19 12:10:52.166661    dog      n1           1           3
   2020-02-19 12:17:25.087898    dog      n1           3           6
   2020-02-19 12:34:27.624939    dog      n2           4           3
   2020-02-19 12:35:50.522116    cat      n1           2           0
   2020-02-19 12:38:49.547181    cat      n2           3           4
```

There should be just one observation for any combination var1 & level. I want to eliminate duplicates and keep only most recent records. in the previous example the first row should be eliminated as dog-n1 from row 2 is more recent. nevertheless, I want to keep row 3 even if var1 is also equal to "dog" because level is different.

so, what I want to obtain:

```
  date                         var1    level       score_1     score_2
   2020-02-19 12:17:25.087898    dog      n1           3           6
   2020-02-19 12:34:27.624939    dog      n2           4           3
   2020-02-19 12:35:50.522116    cat      n1           2           0
   2020-02-19 12:38:49.547181    cat      n2           3           4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
df %>%
group_by(var1, level) %>%
filter(date == max(date)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Comment: There is no need to install the whole `tidyverse`, `dplyr` should be enough for your solution (we often forget that not everybody has `tidyverse` installed (yet) and it's quite a big collection of big packages)

Comment: True story. I also forget which subpackages within `tidyverse` have what functions sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

In base R, use `duplicated`. Looks like your data is already sorted by date, so you can use

```
df[!duplicated(df[c("var1", "level")], fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

(by default, `duplicated` will give `FALSE` for the *first* occurrence of anything, and `TRUE` for every other occurrence. Setting `fromLast = TRUE` will make reverse the direction, so the *last* occurrence is kept)

If you're not sure your data is already sorted, sort it first!

```
df = df[order(df$var1, df$level, dfd$date), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.table` approach as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(date)], .(var1, level)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another *tidyverse* answer, using `dplyr::slice_max()`.

To demonstrate with a reproducible example, here is `flights` data from `nycflights13` package:

```r
library(nycflights13) # for the data
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

my_flights <- # a subset of 3 columns
  flights |> 
  select(carrier, dest, time_hour)

my_flights # preview of the subset data
#> # A tibble: 336,776 × 3
#>    carrier dest  time_hour          
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dttm>             
#>  1 UA      IAH   2013-01-01 05:00:00
#>  2 UA      IAH   2013-01-01 05:00:00
#>  3 AA      MIA   2013-01-01 05:00:00
#>  4 B6      BQN   2013-01-01 05:00:00
#>  5 DL      ATL   2013-01-01 06:00:00
#>  6 UA      ORD   2013-01-01 05:00:00
#>  7 B6      FLL   2013-01-01 06:00:00
#>  8 EV      IAD   2013-01-01 06:00:00
#>  9 B6      MCO   2013-01-01 06:00:00
#> 10 AA      ORD   2013-01-01 06:00:00
#> # … with 336,766 more rows
```

Grouping by `carrier` & `dest`, we can see many rows for each group.

```r
my_flights |> 
  count(carrier, dest)
#> # A tibble: 314 × 3
#>    carrier dest      n
#>    <chr>   <chr> <int>
#>  1 9E      ATL      59
#>  2 9E      AUS       2
#>  3 9E      AVL      10
#>  4 9E      BGR       1
#>  5 9E      BNA     474
#>  6 9E      BOS     914
#>  7 9E      BTV       2
#>  8 9E      BUF     833
#>  9 9E      BWI     856
#> 10 9E      CAE       3
#> # … with 304 more rows
```

So if we want to deduplicate those in-group rows by taking the *most recent* `time_hour` value, we could utilize `slice_max()`

```r
my_flights |> 
  group_by(carrier, dest) |> 
  slice_max(time_hour)
#> # A tibble: 329 × 3
#> # Groups:   carrier, dest [314]
#>    carrier dest  time_hour          
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dttm>             
#>  1 9E      ATL   2013-05-04 07:00:00
#>  2 9E      AUS   2013-02-03 16:00:00
#>  3 9E      AVL   2013-07-13 11:00:00
#>  4 9E      BGR   2013-10-17 21:00:00
#>  5 9E      BNA   2013-12-31 15:00:00
#>  6 9E      BOS   2013-12-31 14:00:00
#>  7 9E      BTV   2013-09-01 12:00:00
#>  8 9E      BUF   2013-12-31 18:00:00
#>  9 9E      BWI   2013-12-31 19:00:00
#> 10 9E      CAE   2013-12-31 09:00:00
#> # … with 319 more rows
```

By the same token, we could have used `slice_min()` to get the rows with the earliest `time_hour` value.